# SQL query results for different values in separate columns?

Tags: sql, database, caching

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6ad5/4

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, votetime), 0), count(vote)
FROM Votes
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, votetime), 0)
```

Basically I have a table of votes and timestamps.  What I want my results to look like is the example below.

```
|Minute|Yes|No|
|2015-03-26 10:45|3|1|
|2015-03-26 10:46|1|2|
|2015-03-26 10:47|4|3|
|2015-03-26 10:48|1|2|
```

I tried nesting select statements (select where yes, select where no, from original select) but had no luck.

Is this possible?  **I should also point out that I don't think I can do tsql.**  I believe this is a cache server on the backend, but I'll readily admit I don't really know what that means.  They gave us a JDBC driver and WinSQL software.  That's pretty much all I know about the environment :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dateadd(s,-1*datepart(s, votetime),votetime) ,
sum(case when vote='Y' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Yes',
sum(case when vote='N' then 1 else 0 end) as 'No'

from votes
group by dateadd(s,-1*datepart(s, votetime),votetime)
```

SQLfillde: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a6ad5/27

Comment: No, the sum and case statements make total sense.  Thank you.